# Umnet dependency errors in ubuntu 15.10

Tags: 15.10, dependencies

I've been getting these umnet dependency errors for quite a lot of things since I installed Ubuntu 15.10.

```
 libxine2-dev : Depends: libxine2-bin (= 1.2.6-1build3) but it is not going to be installed
 linux-generic : Depends: linux-headers-generic (= 4.2.0.30.33) but 4.2.0.25.27 is to be installed
 linux-signed-generic : Depends: linux-headers-generic (= 4.2.0.30.33) but 4.2.0.25.27 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

This is an example of the recent one I got today. What should I do to fix this? 'apt-get -f install' never solves the problem and always asks to do the same again. :(

Comment: @MostafaAhangarha Did you read the post? It says they tried that.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below commands to remove it.

```
 apt-get remove libxine2-dev linux-generic linux-generic
```

after that

```
 apt-get update
```

Hopes it will work.